# Hide/Change javascript prompt title

Tags: javascript, prompt

I am using the following code to show a prompt to get the user's name:

```
var name = prompt('Enter your name', 'name');
```

The problem is that the prompt is showing the title as `index.html` which is the name of the html file that invokes the prompt. Either I need to change the title or I need to remove the title entirely since showing the file name as header is totally weird. What can I do about it?

**EDIT**

My `index.html` has a title tag that looks like following:

```
<title>My Page</title>
```

Comment: A page without (or empty) `<title>` tag is invalid anyway.

Comment: `index.html` DO have a `<title>` tag

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using ? With most of the browsers, I don't even have a title bar on the prompt.

Comment: I am having the problem with UIWebView in IOS7, which is based on safari to the best of my knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons this is impossible. You can use some custom prompt other than the basic one like $.dialog of jQueryUI

Comment: So there is no way I can't even display my html's TITLE as the prompt header? What security issue do that cause?

Comment: Its a `security/anti-phishing` feature of javascript itself.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not true, but some reference to back up the security claim would be nice.